# C++ setter doesn't change variable value

Tags: c++, setter

I've class `Restaurant` containing map of `Order`. Every order has a number. I need to maintain if an order isn't paid or already is. I've got variable `isPaid` in `Order` class, it's false defaultly.

The method `Order::pay()` should change it to true. It's kind of setter. However, it doesn't work. In main you can see, it returns `0`in both cases, however, in second case should return `1` because it's already paid. 
Maybe there's possibility to call the method from Restaurant class, however, I'd prefer to call it from Order class by something like: `restaurant.getOrder(1).pay()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Order {
    bool isPaid = false;

public:
    bool getIsPaid() {
        return isPaid;
    }

    void pay() {
        isPaid = true;
    }
};

class Restaurant {
    map<int, Order> allOrders;

public:
    void addOrder(int number) {
        Order order = Order();
        allOrders.insert(pair<int, Order>(number, order));
    }

    Order getOrder(int number) {
        return allOrders[number];
    }
};

int main() {
    Restaurant restaurant;
    restaurant.addOrder(1);
    cout << restaurant.getOrder(1).getIsPaid() << endl;
    restaurant.getOrder(1).pay();
    cout << restaurant.getOrder(1).getIsPaid() << endl;
}
```

Result:

> ```
> 0
> 0
> ```

Comment: You are returning by value the order, that copy gets updated. Return a reference instead (thousands of similar questions here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The member function

```
Order getOrder(int number);
```

returns the object by value. When you "pay" as in

```
restaurant.getOrder(1).pay();
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a copy
```

you operate on a temporary copy of the order instance. You can fix this as suggested by @MatthieuBrucher in the comments by e.g. changing the function signature to

```
Order& getOrder(int number);
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
restaurant.getOrder(1).pay();
```

the `restaurant.getOrder(1)` returns a copy of the order, you set the `bool` in that copy. Consider redesigning your class, returning references to your internals is not always a good idea. You might be better off with something like this:

```
class Restaurant {
    ...
    public: void processPayment(int orderNumber) {
        auto order = allOrders.find(orderNumber);
        if (order == std::end(allOrders)) { throw std::invalid_argument(); }
        order->second.pay();
    }
    ...
};
```